# Can't find out how to work with recyvler view '{' expected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

what I am trying to do is implement a recycler view. I am using one that has been implemented already, but when I change the names to the new project, it says "'{' expected" or "class expeceted". I do not quite get where is the error. Any help or suggestions would be great, thanks

```
public class TransferProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TransferProductAdapter.TransferProductViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private List<TransferProduct> transferProductList;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;
    Context context;

    public TransferProductAdapter(List<TransferProduct> transferProductList, Context context){
        this.transferProductList = transferProductList;
        this.context = context;
    }

@NonNull
@Override
public TransferProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_transfer_product, viewGroup, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new TransferProductViewHolder(v);
}
}
```

Edited the code

Comment: Please first follow any tutorial about **RecyclerView** and then try to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `extends` keyword.

Comment: I just figured it out. Thanks any way!

Comment: But now I get "class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onbindviewholder" error, any suggestions there? I editted the code

Comment: You have to implement the abstract methods. please refer the documentation

Comment: Move your cursor over the red-underlined words, left click, press ALT+ENTER, then again ENTER

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the class